# Can object pointers be passed between CLR and native C++?

Tags: visual-c++, dll, c++-cli, marshalling, void-pointers

I have been trying to pass a class pointer from a native DLL to CLR. I am not so successful with it. I get to the point it returns the pointer using void * and later converting it to ClassType * using IntrPtr and ToPointer(). But the minute I try to access its member methods, its not able to get the old property values. I get instead 0 and some random values.

I have even tried to use VC100 as the toolset for both the CLR and native dll. Still I get the value "Error reading characters of string".

I tried to google and can't find much info on passing object pointers from native to CLR. I have referred to even the [step-by-step](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-minutes#A8) available in code project.

Edited to add this:

---

I have a native dll where a function that returns object pointer

Native.dll:

```
#if defined EXPORTDLL // inside DLL
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else // outside DLL
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

.....

DLL_EXPORT void*  SomeMethod(uint16_t num1, const char * str1, const char * str2)
{
  Obj1 obj(...);
  ...
  return (void*)&obj; // <- at this point it is still correct
}

....
class DLL_EXPORT Obj1{
....
const std::string var1;
const std::string var2;
const std::string var3;
....
DLL_EXPORT strct1 memberFunction1()
{
   // do something with the variables
   // here when its called by managed code, the var1, var2, var3 shows random values and bad ptr..
}
...
}
```

And later in managed code clr I call the memberFunct1 using the return pointer.

```
[DllImport("Native.dll", EntryPoint = "?SomeMethod@@YAPAVstruct1@someSpace@@GV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@0@Z", CallingConvention = CallingConvention::Cdecl)]
IntPtr * SomeMethod(uint16_t num1, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType::LPStr)]String^  str1, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType::LPStr)] String^ str2);
.....

String^ str1 = gcnew String("1223568");
String^ str2 = gcnew String("1.2.3.5");
Obj1 *objptr = (Obj1*)(SomeMethod(1,str1, str2)).ToPointer();
// <- at this point the objptr properties are showing garbage
objptr->memberFunction1();
```

I use this obj1 pointer to call a member method but in the member method the member values are showing as bad ptr.

---

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks in advance.

---

I have added an additional method in my Native dll.

```
void DLL_EXPORT SomeMethod2(int i1, const char* var1, const char* var2, Obj1* retval);
```

And called it from my CLR project

```
[DllImport("Native.dll", EntryPoint = "?SomeMethod2@@YAXHPBD0PAVObj1@@@Z", CallingConvention = CallingConvention::Cdecl)]
void SomeMethod2(int i1, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType::LPStr)]String^ var1, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType::LPStr)]String^  var2, Obj1* retval);
....
Obj1 * testPtr3;
SomeMethod2(1, (char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(str1), (char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(str2), testPtr3);
SomeMethod2(1, str1, str2, testPtr3);

Obj1  testPtr2 = Obj1(1, (char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(str1), (char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(str2));
```

But I get link errors? I have already linked it??!!??

error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000356) "public: __thiscall Obj1::Obj1(int,char const *,char const *)" (??0Obj1@@$$FQAE@HPBD0@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl main(void)" (?main@@$$HYAHXZ)

error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00035B) "void __cdecl SomeMethod2(int,char const *,char const *,class Obj1 *)" (?SomeMethod2@@$$FYAXHPBD0PAVObj1@@@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl main(void)" (?main@@$$HYAHXZ)

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Obj1::Obj1(int,char const *,char const *)" (??0Obj1@@$$FQAE@HPBD0@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl main(void)" (?main@@$$HYAHXZ)

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl SomeMethod2(int,char const *,char const *,class Obj1 *)" (?SomeMethod2@@$$FYAXHPBD0PAVObj1@@@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl main(void)" (?main@@$$HYAHXZ)

[image]

Comment: @Martin Sorry, I have edited my post and added some codes.

Comment: This is a bog standard [dangling pointer bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).  A very common bug in a C or C++ program, usually very hard to diagnose.  But not when you use pinvoke, the stack space required by the pinvoke marshaller ensures that `obj` gets overwritten reliably.  You have to store it elsewhere, the best place is almost always the stack frame of the caller.  Change the return type to void and add an `Obj1* retval` parameter.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried yours too. But I still get Link error. I have edited my post to include what you have mentioned and added an image showing the link.

Comment: @ras - from the screenshot - *remove* the `Native.dll` from the ClrDLLWrapper project

Comment: @MartinBa - I have removed it. Still have the link error.

Answer (score 1):

You do not use C++/CLI in this way!

The whole *point* of C++/CLI is to act as a glue between the .NET world and the native world.

What you do instead is to:

- Include the C++ headers for `SomeMethod` and `class Obj1` in the C++/CLI source file and
- have the C++/CLI assembly reference the `Native.dll` project

Then, you can simply use it as you would normally in C++ - [convert any CLR types to native representation first](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/311259) (System::String can be converted by MFC `CString` if you include MFC):

```
String^ str1 = gcnew String("1223568");
String^ str2 = gcnew String("1.2.3.5");
Obj1 *objptr = SomeMethod(1, CString(str1), CString(str2));
```

---

As for why you see garbage in the debugger: It is probably because **you return the address of a local object**:

```
DLL_EXPORT void*  SomeMethod(uint16_t num1, const char * str1, const char * str2)
{
  Obj1 obj(...);
  ...
  return (void*)&obj; // <- at this point it is still correct
}
```

In this case, `obj`will be cleaned up (its D'tor invoked and its stack memory recycled) as soon as you return from `SomeMethod`.

- Either return the object by value
- or `new` up the object and return the pointer. (though that is leak-risking code)

Comment: I have done this. I have included the header file and copied the Native.dll and added it as a reference to my CLR project. I instantiated it and I get a Link error??!??  [error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00041D) "public: __thiscall SomeDLLClass1::SomeDLLClass1(int,char const *,char const *)" (??0SomeDLLClass1@@$$FQAE@HPBD0@Z) referenced in function "int __clrcall main(cli::array<class System::String ^ >^)" ]

Comment: The insantiation line[Obj1  testPtr2 = Obj1(1, (char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(str1), (char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(str2));]

Comment: @ras - you do not copy the Native.dll and add it as a reference. You have to add the Native.vcxproj as a reference and activate `Link Lib Dependencies == true`. - alternatively, you link to the `.lib` file from the native project, if the native project lives in a nother solution.

Comment: I have added the reference via Project > properties and have set Link Lib Dependencies to true. It is showing an exclamation mark on it and still has the same Link errors.